# Grid in the back of boxplot in R

Tags: r, plot, grid

I want to add a grid to my `boxplot`, if I use `grid` the grid get in front of my plot. How can i put this grid in the back?

[image]

The code I am using is the following

```
library(dplyr)
input <- mtcars[,c('mpg','cyl')]
print(head(input))
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, xlab = "Number of Cylinders",
        ylab = "Miles Per Gallon")
grid(nx=16, ny=16)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not he most elegant way, but you can draw first a boxplot without color border, axis labeling and frame, add your grid and then add boxplot over by using the argument `add = TRUE`:

```r
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, xlab = "Number of Cylinders",
        ylab = "Miles Per Gallon", border = NA, 
        xaxt='n', yaxt = "n", frame = FALSE)
grid(nx=16, ny=16)
boxplot(mpg ~ cyl, data = mtcars, xlab = "Number of Cylinders",
        ylab = "Miles Per Gallon", add = TRUE, ann = FALSE)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: `border = NA` is enough

Comment: @Marcinthebox, you're totally right ;) Thanks for the tip. I'm editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ggplot2:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  xlab("Number of Cylinders") +
  ylab("Miles Per Gallon") +
  theme_bw()
```

---

[image]

The vertical gridlines seem redundant.

Comment: You may want to use custom theme as 
  `theme(panel.grid = element_line(linetype = "dashed", colour = "black"),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray97"))`

Comment: [ggplot quick help](https://groups.google.com/group/ggplot2/attach/916e6043b542b18d/ggplot2%204-1.pdf?part=0.1&authuser=0) and [ggplot cheatsheet](https://rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf) for reference.